# Having an issue with the take() property

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angular-promise

I am trying to retrieve a single object from firebase using a key. Instead of implementing OnDestroy for the .subscribe() method, I want to use the take() property instead to just get a single object and be done with done with it.

The issue is I get a error that "property take does not exist on type void"
 and the error in the console is "Undefined is not an object". I have searched and can't seem to figure out the solution.

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();

    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (id)  {
      this.productService.get(id).take(1).subscribe(p => this.product = p);
    }
  }
```

I have imported rxjs/add/operator/take.

EDIT:
Below is my ProductService class

```
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  create(product) {
    return this.db.list('/products').push(product);
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges();
  }

  get(productId) {
    return this.db.object('/products/' + productId);
  }

}
```

This is the error I get in the console:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
>   this.productService.get(id).take is not a function. (In
>   'this.productService.get(id).take(1)',
>   'this.productService.get(id).take' is undefined)

Comment: Where is your `productService` code? The problem is `productService.get()` is returning undefined.

Comment: Hi @mdewitt, I added my productservice class with the productservice.get() method. If it helps, this is the error I get in the console: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.productService.get(id).take is not a function. (In 'this.productService.get(id).take(1)', 'this.productService.get(id).take' is undefined)

Comment: I'm not sure but this question doesn't seem to be related to [tag:angularjs].  It *might* be [tag:angular], and it also seems to be [tag:typescript] rather than [tag:javascript];  You might want to go through your tags again and figure out which ones *actually* apply.

Comment: It seems like the problem might be that your `get` isn't returning a `list` that you need to `take` one from, it's returning a single `object` already.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/456) help? `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';`

Comment: I added Typescript to the flags. I imported Observable from rxjs/Rx and still getting errors.

Comment: Try renaming your `get` function name to something different than `get` (like `getById`). I suspect that `get` is a reserved word (for getters) then you're getting unexpected results.

Comment: Thank you to all who helped me out here. @Uber5001's answer solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to call `take` on somehting that's not an Observable.

My guess is that `this.productService.get(id)` is of type [`AngularFireObject<T>`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/database/object/create-reference.ts)):

```
export interface AngularFireObject<T> {
  query: DatabaseQuery;
  valueChanges(): Observable<T | null>;
  snapshotChanges(): Observable<SnapshotAction>;
  update(data: Partial<T>): Promise<void>;
  set(data: T): Promise<void>;
  remove(): Promise<void>;
}
```

You need to use `valueChanges` (or `snapshotChanges`) to get an Observable:

`this.productService.get(id).valueChanges().take(1).subscribe(p => this.product = p);`

See also: [Retrieving data as objects](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md)

Comment: This fixed my issue. I was adding .valueChanges() and snapshotChanges() to the get method directly. Thank you so much Sir.